# React Native UI Issue in Samsung Z fold devices

Tags: react-native

I am using React Native version 0.70.0. When I run the React Native application for the first time on a Samsung Z Fold 3 mobile device, it appears to work fine. However, as soon as I fold and then unfold the device, the UI becomes distorted. The UI also becomes distorted when I leave it as a background process. If I open it from the beginning after unfolding, the UI will appear correctly.

I have used Dimension,pixelRatio,and 'react-native-size-matters' to make it responsive.

In my opinion, I can't understand this screen dimension. The view on which I start the application remains the same, even when it should change. What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting foldable devices in your app, you should know that screen folding/unfolding triggers a change in the screen size constants (from Dimension or useDimension() etc).

So you should listen to change events by hooking to the 'change' event, and update the sizes where necessary (in your JSX or stylesheets).

A great example can be found here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions